# Figure out rate of change of speed for fixed distance

Tags: physics

Say I have two points. I know the distance between those points. And let's say I have a bobbin that's starting at point A at a fixed speed of 100 jiggers/second

By point B, I want my bobbin to only be traveling 20 jiggers/second.

What equation can I use to figure out what rate of change of speed I would need to apply to my bobbin to slow it down to 20 jiggers/second?

How would I do it so that it eased into the new speed?

I apologize if this is poorly worded or an asininely easy question. I'm a game developer, and I'm not really sure how to ask this question in a Google-friendly fashion.

Comment: Isn't a jigger a measure of volume, not distance?

Comment: So you want a constant acceleration, right? The answer will be in, say, $m/s^2$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, $jiggers/sec^2$. At least that's what I figured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic [kinematics problem](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/1DKin/U1L6a.cfm), in which two things are known:

The distance between points: $d$

The initial and final velocities: $v_f=100$ j/s and $v_i=20$ j/s

To find the desired acceleration, use the equation:

$$v_f^2=v_i^2+2ad$$

Where $a$ is the acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer! I'll read up on it some more.

Comment: So, solving for $a$, it's looking like $\frac{v_{f}^2 - v_{i}^2}{2d} = a$, is that about right?

Comment: @dclowd9901 Yes, that is exactly right.